# Directory search using recursive thread working only without threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion

I tried to build a recursive directory search with threads but somehow its not working and if i try doing it with out threads it does work i don't understand why. Searched servel places on the web but no couldn't find any solution to my problem if you see what inside /* */ is the method with out thread that does work.

```
class Program
{
    private static List<string> files = new List<string>();
    public static bool FolderContainName(DirectoryInfo source, string name)
    {
        FileInfo[] files = source.GetFiles(name);
        return (files.Length <= 0);
    }

    public static void FileLocataion(DirectoryInfo source, string sFileName)
    {
        if (!FolderContainName(source,sFileName))
        {
            files.Add(source.ToString());
        }
        DirectoryInfo [] newSource = source.GetDirectories();
        if (newSource.Length>0)
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < newSource.Length; i++)
            {
                Thread a = new Thread(() => FileLocataion(newSource[i],sFileName));
                a.Start();
            }
        }

        /*if (!FolderContainName(source, sFileName))
        {
            files.Add(source.ToString());
        }
        DirectoryInfo[] newSource = source.GetDirectories();
        if (newSource.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newSource.Length; i++)
            {
                FileLocataion(newSource[i], sFileName);
            }
        }*/

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter locataion:");
        DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter file name:");
        string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
        files.Clear();
        FileLocataion(source, fileName);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count;i++ )
            Console.WriteLine(files[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. *does not work* is not a good problem description. 2. you're firing off the threads and not waiting for them to finish. 3. This is an I/O bound process, not a CPU bound process so threading won't help. 4. Uncontrolled thread creation can quickly become a CPU hog.

Comment: Threading will help if his problem is an unresponsive GUI. You are right though that is is a BAD idea to make one thread per subdir. Another problem is the files list being accessed by multiple threads.That will not work correctly, that is for sure.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski +1 - Off the top of my head, If he is not waiting for the thread finish, the application finishes. Also, as you stated, this is a bad uses of threading,

Comment: Sorry its my first time here, the problem is it crashes because "out of bonds" or it give the right result but half way only 1 result instead of 3 instances of the same name for the file. What should i do instead so i could use threads to make my search work faster

Comment: @canahari If that's the issue then the whole thing should still be written synchronously and in one thread, and then the whole operation should be wrapped in a call to offload it from the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy yes. I wrote the same thing, maybe not clearly enough.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, each of your threads are trying to add things to a `List`, which is not thread-safe. Use instead for example an object in `System.Collections.Concurrent`

Second, `FileLocation` will return almost immediately and you are trying to read the result before they are constituted. Take a look at `Task` and `async/await`, which will help you handle that.

[This article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) is a good start.

Oh, and by the way, there is already builtin fonctions in C# to recursively list a directory:

```
var myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(extractPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: I know there is already a function like this but i try to create my own for h.w

Comment: OK. So ignore my last remark and focus on the remaining ones :-) Async/await are very powerful features of C# and are worth the time spent to fully understand them

Comment: @user1930686 And then you just go and ask other people to do the whole thing for you?  If you're not actually going to do it yourself, you might as well just use the .NET method.

Comment: I'm trying to do my self just don't understand my problem